# Why did I get undefined values when trying to read xml file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, html

I am trying to read data from a xml file and display them in my html file, but when I am trying to display my values I get "undefined" values for all the values.
I am a really new with ajax and xml so excuse my code if its horrible! I will appreciate if someone got a really briefly answer.

Here's my xml file:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2019-01-25">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1346"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="124.72"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.697"/>
            <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4664"/>
            <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.86580"/>
                          ....
```

My javascript code:

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            returndata(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "rates.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function returndata(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>currency</th><th>rates</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("currency")[0] +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("rate")[0] +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

When I click the button I got the following result:

```
currency    rates
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined    
.....
```

UPDATE Javascript code(fixed):

```
function returndata(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>currency</th><th>rates</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
    for (i = 2; i <x.length; i++) {

          table += "<tr><td>" +
              x[i].getAttribute("currency") +
              "</td><td>" +
              x[i].getAttribute("rate") +
              "</td></tr>";

    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Okay now it works, thank you very much, i started my variable from the value 2 because when i am trying to have a while loop like (x!=null) my webpage it still loading forever and then breaks down..

i tried that one:

```
function returndata(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<tr><th>currency</th><th>rates</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        while (x!=null) {
          table += "<tr><td>" +
              x[i].getAttribute("currency") +
              "</td><td>" +
              x[i].getAttribute("rate") +
              "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: Few things wrong here, 1: The first `Cube` element doesn't have currency or rate, neither does the second. 2: You are attempting to get the elements `currency` and `rate` but they aren't elements, they are attributes

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to see how to get the attribute value. Update your code to check if the attribute has a value before adding it to the table.

Comment: @AdamH thank you very much i managed to get it working!! However i wanted to ask, why i have the null values?

Comment: The `while` loop never changes `x`, so if you go into the loop it will run infinitely. I think you meant `if (x != null)`.

Comment: Actually, I think you meant to put `if (x != null)` around the `for` loop.

Comment: But there's no need for that. `getElementsByTagName` never returns `null`. If there are no elements with that tag it returns an empty array, and the `for` loop won't do anything.